# Should I limit user input length?

Tags: validation, user-input, string-length

I've asked myself this question as I've rarely seen people checking for the length of user input in their backend. Should I do this in general?

I am always validating user-input using PHP's `htmlentities()` function to prevent XSS, however should I check for string length as well?

I guess this could lead to database errors at best when inserting to a database but are there any real security concerns?

Answer (score 0):

When storing the data on the database, and the column has a limit. It's better to validate the length of the field before trying to store the data. Otherwise you will have to deal with those exceptions or even worse, return unexpected errors to the user without giving them the opportunity to fix it.

If there's no limit to store the data, there's no need to validate the length of text field. Although you need to be aware of limits imposed by your database.

For example,

- to have no limit on ORACLE you need to use a BLOB. VARCHAR has a hard limit of 4000 bytes.
- PostgreSQL does not have the same limitation a VARCHAR without limit
  is like a TEXT column.
- On MariaDB VARCHAR can have a maximum of 8000 bytes.

Talking about security, I can't see any problems with the length, if you have a public form that accepts BLOB/TEXT, it might be a good idea to add a meaningul limit, but it's not a requirement. You would have to add a captcha to avoid bots anyway.

In resume, add a limit on the backend when you need one, and be aware of the limit imposed by your storage system.